# ruby Marshal serialization

Tags: ruby, marshalling

thanks for your time!

I get a class like this

```
class Vuser

    def initialize (logfile_name, iteration_hash)
        @logfile_name = logfile_name
        @iteration_hash = iteration_hash
    end

    attr_accessor :logfile_name, :iteration_hash

    def output_iteration_info ()
        puts @logfile_name
        puts @iteration_hash
    end
end
```

And there's will be an array to store the instance of Vuser Class. Let's say the array's name is vuser_ary.

I want to store this array ( vuser_ary ) to a binary file and I think it's called serialization. I google it and find Marshal in the standard library can do this.
Here's an example how I do this according to the example on the Internet :

```
#serialization
File.open("some.file","wb") do |file|
   Marshal.dump(vuser_ary,file)
end

#loading
vuser_ary = nil
File.open("some.file","rb") {|f| vuser_ary = Marshal.load(f)}
```

But when I check the size of some.file. I find it's just four bytes. Then I realize that the data stored in some.file may be the reference but not the value of the vuser_ary.

Then my question is how do I store the value of vuser_ary to a binary file. How do I change my code to achieve that? Thanks in advance!

BTW: the value stored in vuser_ary will be like this :

RO_3.2_S4_CommericalRealEstate1_274.log

{1=>"Fail", 2=>"Fail", 3=>"Pass", 4=>"Pass", 5=>"Fail"}

RO_3.2_S4_CommericalRealEstate1_275.log

{11=>"Fail", 2=>"Fail", 3=>"Fail", 4=>"Pass", 5=>"Fail"

RO_3.2_S4_CommericalRealEstate1_276.log

{1=>"Fail", 2=>"Fail", 3=>"Pass", 4=>"Pass", 5=>"Fail"}

RO_3.2_S4_CommericalRealEstate1_277.log

{1=>"Fail", 2=>"Fail", 3=>"Pass", 4=>"Pass", 5=>"Fail"}

RO_3.2_S4_CommericalRealEstate1_278.log

{1=>"Fail", 2=>"Fail", 3=>"Pass", 4=>"Pass", 5=>"Fail"}

RO_3.2_S4_CommericalRealEstate1_279.log

{1=>"Fail", 2=>"Fail", 3=>"Pass", 4=>"Pass", 5=>"Fail"}

RO_3.2_S4_CommericalRealEstate1_280.log

{1=>"Fail", 2=>"Fail", 3=>"Fail", 4=>"Pass", 5=>"Fail"}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Four bytes? It so happens that marshalling the empty array `[]` produces a 4-byte string on my Ruby:

```
> Marshal.dump([]).length
 => 4
```

Are you sure `vuser_ary` isn't empty when you try marshalling it?

As it happens, there's no difference between a "reference" to an object and the object itself: there are no pointers in Ruby, so if you have an array (and it's non-empty), then it'll get marshalled:

```
> Marshal.dump([1, 2, 3]).length
 => 10
```

For good measure:

```
> vuser_ary = [{1=>"Fail", 2=>"Fail", 3=>"Pass", 4=>"Pass", 5=>"Fail"}]
 => [{1=>"Fail", 2=>"Fail", 3=>"Pass", 4=>"Pass", 5=>"Fail"}] 
> Marshal.dump(vuser_ary).length
 => 72
```

Comment: Thank you Len. I reviewed my scripts and found out vuser_ary was empty at that step. In fact I was focusing on the reference and value thing yesterday and you really help me a lot~